# Can SHA256 EVP_DigestUpdate be used for small data blocks?

Tags: c, sha

My plain C application collects data blocks and concatenates them to a multi-GB file. The size of the incoming data blocks is random between 1 byte and 256KB, and is out of my control. 
I'd like to calculate the sha256 hash while collecting incoming blocks, such that it matches the sha256sum hash of the large resulting file. My starting point is the openssl example at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_DigestUpdate.html . Whenever a new block arrives, I call my update routine below.

```
void AddToReadResults(uint32_t bytes)
{
    if(bytes) EVP_DigestUpdate(RdrMdContext, GetHeadBuffer(), bytes);
    TotalBytes += bytes;
}
```

Given the same set of data blocks as input, I get a consistent repeatable hash. But it does not match the sha256sum of the large concatenated file.

Comment: In principle, this is no problem. There is probably an implementation issue somewhere in your code, which unfortunately you do not share with us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ctx. I think I nailed it down to my own silly mistake. Before writing to the large file, the data goes through LZO compression, so obviously the hash will be different. Omitting LZO does provide the right hash.